# Configuration Node.Js on Jenkins on Mac

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Do you know how to install NodeJs in Jenkins with a MacOs ? I've tried to install it automatically but when I build a job I got this error `Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'`.
I tried to install node in the right folder but I already have an installation of node so it doesn't work. Does anyone know what to put in those field ? [sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49N03.png)

Comment: are you sure this is related to Jenkins? What happens when you try to execute manually the steps on the job outside of Jenkins?

Comment: It works because node is well installed on my environment. Actually this is the problem because Jenkins want to use the npm installed in path/to/jenkins/tools/node, but this installation is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding that :

`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

I don't know if it's the better way to do it but it works because Jenkins now use the node js installation of my machine.